# How to display confirmation message with GridView ShowDeleteButton CommandField

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controls, linkbutton, directcast

I'm trying to attach a Javascript function to confirm a delete of a record in a GridView. I know this can be done more easily using an asp:LinkButton in an ItemTemplate but I am trying to attach it to a CommandField - ShowDeleteButton button.

I've tried to follow this tutorial: [display-confirmation-message-on-gridview-deleting](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/02/22/display-confirmation-message-on-gridview-deleting.aspx)

I am new to GridView and my implementation is in VB.Net not C#. Here is the code where I try to inject the Javascript function and I cannot figure out how/why my row.cell references are wrong:

```vb
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) _
    Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowState <> DataControlRowState.Edit Then
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then  'check for RowType DataRow
            Dim id As String = e.Row.Cells(0).Text      'get the position to be deleted
           Try
            'cast the ShowDeleteButton link to linkbutton
            Dim lb As LinkButton
            Dim i As Integer = 4            'cell we want in the row (relative to 0 not 1) 
            lb = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(i).Controls(2), LinkButton)
            If lb IsNot Nothing Then        'attach the JavaScript function with the ID as the parameter
                lb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ConfirmOnDelete('" & id & "');")
            End If
           Catch ex As Exception
           End Try
        End If
    End If
```

Here is my GridView markup snippet (a bit more busy than all bound columns; I count 3 TemplateField items after the first and only BoundField to arrive at the 5th column hence i = 4 above):

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PositionID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="true" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PositionTitle">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("PositionTitle")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPositionTitle" Text='<%# Eval("PositionTitle")%>' />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Incumbent">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Incumbent")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Incumbent")%>' Visible = "false"></asp:Label>            
            <asp:DropDownList Width="100%" runat="server" 
               id="ddlUsers" AutoPostBack="true" 
               DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="UserID"
               OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsers_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList> 
        </EditItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Backup">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#Eval("Backup")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblBackup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Backup")%>' Visible = "false"></asp:Label>         
            <asp:DropDownList Width="100%" runat="server" 
               id="ddlUsersBackup" AutoPostBack="true" 
               DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="UserID"
               OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsersBackup_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList> 
        </EditItemTemplate>     
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="coolbutton" 
        ShowEditButton="true" 
        ShowDeleteButton="true"
        ShowCancelButton="true" />
```

When I ignore the error, the Command buttons are indeed in the 5th column:

[image: When I ignore the error, the Command buttons are indeed in the 5th column.]

The error I get without the Try/Catch is: 
[image: Problem on DirectCast]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't figured out yet, your problem is in `ButtonType="Button"` here:

```
 <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="coolbutton" 
        ShowEditButton="true" 
        ShowDeleteButton="true"
        ShowCancelButton="true" />
```

You can't cast a command button to link button. You have to define it as Link button (please refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.aspx) for details of CommandField class). This is working:

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ControlStyle-CssClass="coolbutton" 
            ShowEditButton="true" 
            ShowDeleteButton="true"
            ShowCancelButton="true" />
```

Comment: Your answer helped me think about this in a new way. Indeed, I changed the ButtonType above to Link and the DirectCast worked. But I did not like the effect. So then, I changed ButtonType back to Button and changed the DirectCast to Button and it all seems to work fine. Still have a bit more testing to do but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just call a javascript function on onclientclick event and ask for confirmation. If it returns true then you can call the server side code to delete.

Below is the code for explanation

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" OnClick="lbDelete_Click" OnClientClick="return fnConfirm();"> Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

And below is the javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnConfirm() {
    if (confirm("The item will be deleted. Are you sure want to continue?") == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

You can check the detailed article with source code in the below link

http://www.dotnetpickles.com/2013/03/how-to-show-confirm-message-while.html

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I found lots of C# answers.

aspx page:

```
<asp:CommandField DeleteText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="true" 
     ButtonType="Button" />
```

aspx.vb page:

```vb
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, _
                                 e As GridViewRowEventArgs) _
                                 Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
     If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        If (e.Row.RowState <> DataControlRowState.Edit) Then
            Dim oButton As Button
            oButton = CType(e.Row.Cells(14).Controls(0), Button)
            oButton.OnClientClick = _
                "if (confirm(""Are you sure you wish to Delete?"") == false) return;"
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```